# Fermat pseudo primes

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving, pseudoprimes

Is it possible for a number of the form $2^p-1$ with $p\in \mathbb{P}$ (the primes) to satisfy $3^{2^p-2}\equiv 1\pmod {2^p-1}$ and not be a prime?

In other words, can a Mersenne number be a Fermat pseudo prime to the base 3?

I tried this but couldn't make much progress. I would appreciate if the solution uses only elementary tools, but any solution is better than none.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can find $a^3$ that divides $n=  2^{p} - 1$ then there will be a non-abelian group of order $n$ and in particular, the group will not be cyclic hence $n$ will not be a Carmichael number. That does not necessarily mean $n$ cannot be a Fermat pseudo prime for the base 3, only that there is some base for which for which non-prime $n$ will be a pseudo prime.